# Select last full column in SQL

Tags: sql, domo

I'm new to SQL, so forgive me if this is silly.

I have a bunch of different rows, each a new match in a game. The columns are defined by minutes. So `min_1`, is the start of the first minute, `min_2` is the start of the second and so on. Each row shows the amount of gold a team has at that time, so for `min_1` its 0, `min_9` its 9012, `min_12` its 14587 etc.

Now I need to find the total gold they had, which in a 12 minute game, would be 14587 in this case. However, not every game is 12 minutes. Some might be 12, some might be 24, most are between 40-50 minutes. After the game ends, the values in my table and just empty. So for this 12 minute game, `min_13` is just blank (the original file is a csv, its in table form so its value will be `null`).

So is there a way in SQL to look on a row, find the last non-empty column, and report the value?

So far my code would be:

```
CASE
  WHEN `blueTeamTag`= 'FNC'
  AND `Type` = 'goldblue'
  THEN <This is where it would select the column>
END
```

Comment: What SQL Software are you using? SQL Server, SQL Developer, MySQL?

Comment: MySQL is the software I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you coding in a language?  If you’re using python you could query each column until you hit a column that contains values.

I use SQL regularly professionally and I can’t think of a way to do this with just SQL.

Comment: I can only use R but I don't know R so it won't help haha. I might just have to find another way to do it

Comment: This is easy to do in R! What SQL are you using? Sql server, Mysql? You can probably figure it out with some google searching

Comment: I'm using something called "Beast Mode" its a feature in Domo, the software I'm using. I believe it uses mySQL syntax, but its different because it doesn't have things like tables, so 'select' doesn't work. I can however do it outside in SQL / R but I don't know anything about R at all